# How to check user has clicked refresh button or close x

Tags: jquery

I have to check in my page that page is unloaded by refresh button or close window button, How is it possible using java script / jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is

```
window.unload = <function>
```

jquery is

```
$(window).unload(<function>)
```

or there are also beforeunload events, it depends on what you are trying to do as to the event timing

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit()
{           
   return "Not leaving page";
}
```

These will be called when the page is unloaded, by refreshing, closing the window/tab or navigating away from it (either by a link or by replacing the url).

Be aware that some people may have browsers that may filter out certain script events or actions - what was it, exactly, that you were trying to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

The 'window.onbeforeunload' event should capture what you're trying to do. It will, however, also get fired if a POST occurs (i.e. user clicks a submit button) or if the user tries to navigate away from the page. I'm sure jQuery has a nice wrapper for this, but you can find some information on the javascript method itself here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

i think both are "unload" events in the Browser. You can try :

```
$(window).unload(function () { 
    alert("QueSeraSera.. lalalala"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After many "goggleing", I finally use this. I hope it helps:

```
$(window).bind('unload', function () {
    if(event.clientY < 0) {  
        alert('Gracias por emplear este servicio');
        endSession(); // here you can do what you want ...
    }  
});
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $(window).unbind('unload');
    // si se devuelve un string, automáticamente se pregunta al usuario por si desea irse o no ....
    // return '';
    //'beforeunload event'; 
    if (event.clientY < 0) {
        alert('Gracias por emplear este servicio');
        endSession();
    }  
}
```